# How to fix these flutter dependencies error? Getting it while using pub get

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**Gettings these errors on using pub get**

```
Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on webdriver 3.0.0 which depends on archive ^3.0.0, every version of flutter_driver from sdk requires archive ^3.0.0.
(1) So, because image >=2.1.14 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on archive ^2.0.0, flutter_driver from sdk is incompatible with image >=2.1.14 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0.

Because flutter_cache_manager >=2.1.2 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on image >=2.1.18 <4.0.0 and flutter_cache_manager >=2.1.0 <2.1.2 depends on image ^2.1.18, flutter_cache_manager >=2.1.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 requires image >=2.1.18 <4.0.0.
And because cached_network_image 2.5.1 depends on flutter_cache_manager ^2.1.0 and flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 depends on image ^2.1.1, if cached_network_image 2.5.1 and flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 then image ^2.1.18.
And because flutter_driver from sdk is incompatible with image >=2.1.14 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 (1), one of flutter_driver any from sdk or cached_network_image 2.5.1 or flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 must be false.
And because fstore depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, cached_network_image 2.5.1 is incompatible with flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1.
So, because fstore depends on both flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 and cached_network_image 2.5.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1;     So, because fstore depends on both flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 and cached_network_image 2.5.1, version solving failed.)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade all the packages used in the project.

Comment: Not able to upgrade